# How nestjs uses @nestjs/swagger to generate documentation on Passport strategies route

Tags: nestjs

I am making [@nestjs/swagger](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger) to generate api documentation. But how do I generate a document for an authenticated route?

nest version

```
λ nest i
NodeJS Version : v10.16.0
[Nest Information]
platform-express version : 6.0.0
passport version         : 6.1.0
swagger version          : 3.1.0
common version           : 6.0.0
core version             : 6.0.0
jwt version              : 6.1.1
```

This is a normal route, I can use '@ApiImplicitBody' to make a document:

```
  @Delete()
  @ApiImplicitBody({
    name: 'id',
    required: true,
    type: String,
  })
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'successfully deleted',
  })
  delete(@Body('id') typeId) {
    return this.typesService.delete(typeId);
  }
```

This route requires [authentication](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication), how can I document this type of route?

```
  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  @ApiOkResponse({
    description: 'result Token',
  })
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
```

I looked at the [Swagger documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger) and tried some of the apis in the '@nestjs/swagger' package, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This achieves the result I want:

route:

```
import { UserLoginDto } from './dto/user-login.dto';

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('login')
  @ApiImplicitBody({ name: '', type: UserLoginDto, })
  @ApiOkResponse({ description: 'result Token' })
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return this.authService.login(req.user);
  }
```

UserLoginDto:

```
import { IsNotEmpty, IsString } from 'class-validator';
import { ApiModelProperty } from '@nestjs/swagger';

export class UserLoginDto {
  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiModelProperty({ example: 'ajanuw', description: '账号' })
  readonly username: string;

  @IsString()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @ApiModelProperty({
    example: '123456',
    description: '密码',
  })
  readonly password: string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decorator `@ApiBearerAuth()` [here in the docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/swagger#bearer-authentication) to get an authenticated route to show up in your swagger file.